# How to style android Date- and TimePicker in API 28

Tags: java, android, datepicker, widget, timepicker

I have build an application in android to pick the date and time with the Date- and TimePicker Widget. At the beginning i was deploying/compiling the app with API Level 19. After setting the API Level up to 28 the whole style of the widgets were changed. 
So i now have to manually style the widgets, but theres no idea where to start. The following pictures show what i need to do.

Pic 1: 

[image]
<sub>(source: [000webhostapp.com](https://brenners-webhorst.000webhostapp.com/howtostyledatepicker2.jpg))</sub>

Pic 2:

[image]
<sub>(source: [000webhostapp.com](https://brenners-webhorst.000webhostapp.com/howtostyledatepicker1.jpg))</sub>

After setting the android:width of the DatePicker in Pic 1 to match_parent the widget doesnt fills out display and leaves a blank space at the right side which is not wished. 
Additionally i want to make the Numbers white and the green Bars in at the top of the widgets should be transparent.

Lots of thanks for every help, where to start or which properties have to be set to achieved the goal.

Answer (score 3):

you should make custom style in styles.xml :

```
   <style name="YourDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
       <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/ts_blue</item>
       <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/ts_blue</item>
       <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/ts_blue</item>
       <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/menu_separator_gray</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/ts_white</item>
       <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
       <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
       <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
   </style>
```

then apply like this:

```
 val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.YourDialog,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                    val formattedDate = DefaultDateFormatter().formatDate(
                            date = Date(calendar.timeInMillis),
                            dateFormat = datePickerReturnDateFormat)

                    filter.id = formattedDate

                    onFilterSelectionDone()
                },
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
```